# SOLR hsin parse error

Tags: solr

I am getting the following error when using the hsin function:
org.apache.lucene.queryParser.ParseException: Cannot parse '(*:* AND *val*:"recip(hsin(12.9365,77.5447,lat,long,3963.205,true), 1, 1, 0)")': Unknown function hsin in FunctionQuery('recip(hsin(12.9365,77.5447,lat,long,3963.205,true), 1, 1, 0)', pos=11)

Has anyone faced this issue? Any ideas how I can solve this? I am using solr version 1.4 and have not tried upgrading yet.

Thanks, 
Sapna

Answer (score 1):

`hsin` and other spatial functions are not available in Solr 1.4.x. Check the [Solr wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery#hsin.2C_ghhsin_-_Haversine_Formula).

If you want this feature right now you could use a [nightly build directly from the build server](https://hudson.apache.org/hudson/job/Solr-trunk/).

Comment: ok thanks Mauricio. It works on my local system, where I incidentally have a 3.0 version installed. I don't recall where I got that from. I don't want an unstable version on my production system, although I would like to get be able to boost results based on geolocation. So, I would like to know if the 3.0 is going to be available in a stable version anytime soon (don't see any info on this on the wiki or anywhere else). If not, is there some other way to get the geolocation boosting accomplished? Thanks for your help!

Comment: @sapna: see Solr roadmap here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR?report=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.project:roadmap-panel

Comment: Thanks for the link Mauricio, although I don't see any timelines here. Approx when do you think 3.1 will be released in a stable version?

Comment: @sapna: it's an open source project, there is no release date. It will be released when all issues have been resolved. If you need a release faster, the only way is contributing yourself.